# Screen flickering in Dell Vostro 5460

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, display, motherboard, multi-boot

My laptop Dell Vostro 5460 recently got flickering screen problem.

During boot up hard drive spins along with the system fans and LEDs flash as they usually do.

Here are my troubleshooting steps:

1. I **connected my laptop to an external monitor** to check if the problem
   is with the screen. But external monitor didn't get any signal from
   my laptop.
2. After that I realized that while starting up my laptop is stuck at
   dell startup logo. I tried to **get into BIOS** and it was successful
   but couldn't do anything in BIOS as I couldn't see anything clearly.
3. I opened up my laptop and and did a **hard reboot** but taking out the
   laptop battery and pressing the power button for 30secs. But no use.
4. Connected back the battery and **took my laptop internal HDD out** of the laptop to
   check if its still stuck at dell logo at start up, but it wasn't. It passed dell logo and shown a error message.
5. I checked **display connection** to the motherboard. Disconnected and
   reconnected. But no use.
6. **Removed the CMOS motherboard battery** for few secs and placed it
   back. But no use.

[**Click here for Video**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgFmotNHBkvV0RQYmgyRkpqM2M/view?usp=drivesdk): Stuck at dell startup logo when HDD plugged in

[**Click here for Video**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwgFmotNHBkvUExVcTQzbF9VcXM/view?usp=drivesdk): Boot pass the dell startup logo when HDD unplugged

Please help me find the problem in my laptop. Is it a motherboard problem? Or HDD problem?

Comment: It's probably the screen going bad. Depending on its age, you may want to look into replacement.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf if its screen problem when you connect to an external monitor it should work, right?

Comment: If the external monitor doesn't get a signal from the laptop, that port could be busted too. Or it's possibly a motherboard issue. With hardware seeming to play such a large factor in this question, our troubleshooting is limited, and you might find it in your best interest to contact Dell about this.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf if its just screen and port problem, why is it stuck at dell startup logo?

Comment: See my previous comment, "or it's possibly a motherboard issue". At this point there are any number of problems with it, and again, **you might find it in your best interest to contact Dell about this.**